# angular local variable binding from http response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, binding

I just wanted to know is there any way to bind variables without bind each other.

```
     this.commissions = res.Data;
     this.oldCommissions = res.Data;
```

When I changed a **'Price'** value of this object `this.commissions`

`this.oldCommissions` also change **'Price'** value.

How can I avoid this is anybody knows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.commissions =angular.copy(res.Data);
 this.oldCommissions =angular.copy(res.Data);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Actually this is for Angular v1.x but I'm using Angular v2.x, there optional solutions for it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to try angular's deep copy funtionality where both variables do not point to the same index.
Please find link for the same - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!

Comment: I would also post the code but @Alireza already beat me to it :P